# How to make Pug syntax highlighting in the Vue template in sublimetext 3

Tags: plugins, vue.js, pug, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I use Pug to define Vue templates (within `<template>` tags, see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGhvG.png) for an example). How can I have Sublime 3 highlight the Pug syntax between those tags? Is there a plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

Install

- Pue Syntax Highlight.sublime-package
- Pug.sublime-package

[image]

Comment: I understand. I have another issue. I don't have a correct determining of JS scope inside pug